# semi complex string replace?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have this text

```
'Random Text', 'a\nb\\c\'d\\', 'ok'
```

I want it to become

```
'Random Text', 'a\nb\c''d\', 'ok'
```

The issue is escaping. Instead of escaping with `\` I now escape only `'` with `''`. This is for a 3rd party program so I can't change it thus needing to change one escaping method to another.

The issue is `\\'`. If i do string replace it will become `\''` rather than `\'`. Also `\n` is not a newline but the actual text `\n` which shouldn't be modified. I tried using regex but I couldn't think of a way to say if `'` replace with `''` else if `\\` replace with `\`. Obviously doing this in two step creates the problem.

How do I replace this string properly?

Comment: When you say "I want it to become," do you want it to be that literal string, or do you just want it to print as that string?  If it helps, preceding a string with an '@' symbol denotes the whole string as literal, so for example @"\\" is printed "\\" and not "\"

Comment: `If I perform a string replace` - can you show the string replace you are trying?

Comment: So the single quotation marks are part of the string, correct?  How are you expecting an algorithm to not turn `'a'` into `''a''`?

Comment: Really, are you asking to map `\'` to `''` and `\\` to `\`, concurrently?

Comment: @Namfuak: You misunderstand. I am reading the text from a file.

Comment: WTF, after someones edit i get downvotes... let me fix this up

Comment: Showing some code could help... I don't see where is the problem... Maybe you want special case for `\\'` and apostrophe not prefixed with `\` (like `[^\]'`)...

Comment: It appears you're working with csv data... you should use a csv reader to read the file (and unescape the strings as necessary), do your replace, then write it back.

Comment: @JeffMercado: It's actually strings in a sql statement with `,` seperating columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue lies in replacing `\\` with `\`, which can then cause *another* replacement if it occurs right before `'`. One technique would be to replace it to an intermediary string first that you're sure will not occur anywhere else, then replace it back after you're done.

```
var str = @"'Random Text', 'a\nb\\c\'d\\', 'ok'";
str.Replace(@"\\", "NON_OCCURRING_TEMP")
    .Replace(@"\'", "''")
    .Replace("NON_OCCURRING_TEMP", @"\");
```

As pointed out by @AlexeiLevenkov, you can also use `Regex.Replace` to do both modifications simultaneously.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(\\\\)|(\\')",
    match => match.Value == @"\\" ? @"\" : @"''");
```

Comment: This looks like a great method. -edit- AFAIK `<TEMPORARY>` is legal in a string and won't be escaped

Comment: +1. If this is the right interpretation using RegEx to find all tokens at once and replace may be another approach [ReguarExpression.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: How would you replaced based on an if statement? Like `\\` -> `\` and `\'` -> `''`? wow even SO has this `\\` problem. The comment isn't right

Comment: @acidzombie24: Right, I was thinking you were building normal SQL queries. But looking at it now, it's obvious that the main problem was when building *strings* within the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Seems voithos' interpretation of the question is the right one. Another approach is to use RegEx to find all tokens at once and replace [ReguarExpression.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx)

Starting point:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"\\\\'|\\'|'");
Console.Write(matches.Replace(@"'a b\nc d\\e\'f\\'", 
   match =>"["+match + "]"));
```

Comment: That gets me `[']a b\nc d\\e[\']f[\\']` how does that help? `\\\` and `\'` hasn't been escaped and i see no way of doing so

Comment: @acidzombie24 - I'm not completely sure what set of tokens you want to find and replace with what. So it is just starting point - `match.value` give you currently matched text that you can replace with whatever you want (i.e. with some sort of `Dictionary<string,string>` lookup or `?:` as 
voithos edit shows)